# CSS Only Selecting Certain Classes

Tags: css

Hi I'm working with a Wordpress template. I have a separate template page for the blog section. On the other pages of the site I have class that works fine and looks like this

```
.post header h2 { display:none; }
```

On the blog page, I add this to the CSS and it works as it should

```
#main .post header h2 { display:block; }
```

However if I try that with other classes like

```
#main .wrapper { background-color:#000000; }
```

Nothing happens. I've tried adding !important, I've also tried writing like such

```
body.page-id-15 #main .wrapper { background-color:#000000; }
```

with no luck. Here is a link to the site. http://gregtregunno.ca/news

Comment: `#main #main` is a non-sequitur.That implies `<div id="main"><div id="main">`. For one, you cannot have duplicate IDs, and you're not likely to have duplicate IDs nested like that anyways.

Comment: I apologize. That was a cut and paste error. I've edited my post.

Comment: why are people down voting / voting to close? This appears to me to be a valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css selector is wrong.

Does not work:

```
#main .wrapper { background-color:#000000; }
```

Does work:

```
.wrapper #main { background-color:#000000; }
```

In the html of the wordpress page, from the link you have supplied, the #main div is located inside of the .wrapper div:

```
...
<div class="wrapper">
    ...
    <div id="main">
        ...
    </div>
    ...
</div>
...
```